# How can I view attributes of $window.sessionStorage in chrome console

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, session-storage

I am working in an AngularJS web project. I want to see the attributes of `$window.sessionStorage` when I am navigating in the application.

How can I view attributes of `$window.sessionStorage` in the Chrome console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the F12 dev tools, you can see Local Storage and Session Storage Keys for current domains on the `Resources` tab, left-hand menu